# Showing LongBlob photos from MySQL on View by using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, servlets, blob

Purpose: show different images on my html page by using AngularJS and just one Servlet (images will change depending on request parameters["id" variable])

Code explanation:

- I send request to the Servlet by passing id=13 as params (see JS
  code)
- Servlet will retrieve the photo stored in the DB having id=13
- The response value will be passed to the variable "image" on $scope

Problem: The image doesn't appear on my view.

Error Chrome console:
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Console.log(response) result: 
Object {data: "����..., status:200, config:Object, statusText:"OK"}

Additional info:

- If I change "id" assignment from
  "Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))" to "13", my image will be properly shown on the Servlet URL, which means the file is correctly retrieved and encoded.
- If I add System.out.println(id) after "int
  id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))", it will be shown 13
  as value, which means params are correctly passed from JS file to Servlet
- The photos I want to show on my view are stored on MySQL as longBlob

-

```
MY HTML CODE: 
... 
<img class="images" src="{{image}}"/>
...
```

-

```
MY ANGULAR JS CODE:

 ...
    $http.get('./ImagesServlet', {params: {id:13}})
    .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response)
       $scope.image = response.data;
    });
...
```

-

```
ImagesServlet CODE:
...
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
PoiDao fetcher = new PoiDao();
try {
    List<PoiImg> image = fetcher.ImgById(id);
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    Blob img = image.get(0).getPhoto();
    InputStream in = img.getBinaryStream();
    int length = (int) img.length();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*JavaScript*

If you don't want to change your `$http` call to expect a *Blob* directly,

```
let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

Otherwise, [**pass `responseType: 'blob'` into it**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) so `response.data` will start as a *Blob*

---

Then convert this to a URL you can access from the HTML page

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // note this will prevent GC of blob
```

---

Finally if you want to be clean, when you're done with this image

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // frees blob to be GCd
```

Comment: Thank you, you're great :)
Things work fine now and images do show up, but I still got this error: 
GET http://localhost:8080/MyProject/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D 404 (Not Found).
What could it be?

Comment: 404 means the server is saying you're trying to access something that doesn't exist

Comment: 404 - Not Found resolved using ng-src directive instead of src :)

Comment: @PaulS. When do I call URL.revokeObjectURL(url)? Immediately after let url.......?

Comment: @NickDiv only revoke the URL when you don't need the resource anymore, e.g. if you have a single page app and the view that needed that asset for is being destroyed then revoke the URL so also let the data be removed from the client's machine. In a lot of cases you never need to worry about revoking the URL as it does eventually get removed by the client's own browser, e.g. it could get removed when they close the browser or after X days